# Simultaneously bluetooth remote (android) and run program

Tags: bluetooth, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I'm a student on a hogeschool in the Netherlands. We're working with the LEGO Mindstorms NXT for a project.

However, I'm using my phone (minddroid and other applications) to drive the NXT, but I don't know how to simultaneously run a program.

For example, I drive it over a black line with the remote, and because the program is running, the sensor sees in the program that if it drives over a black line, it has to stop.

Comment: Hi Tim, Welcome to Stack Overflow. More details would help more people to answer your question. Example: is your question how to get the NXT to both communicate on bluetooth and monitor the line at the same time? Or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I meant that I wanted to run a program simultaneously with the bluetooth remote. 
But I solved it, I connected the nxt with a mobile app, so I could only send direct commands. I solved it by connecting with the program, not the nxt robot.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Is your question how to get the NXT to both communicate on bluetooth and monitor the line at the same time? If so:

Then there are two general solutions:

**Main Loop**

In your main loop, first check for communications from the bluetooth system, and then check the sensor to see if the black line is detected. Then repeat.

**Interrupt**

In this solution, the main process would handle communications with the Android phone. The line sensor would be setup to cause a program interrupt when it detects the black line.

The interrupt service routine (ISR) would either set a flag to indicate that the robot should stop or would directly stop the robot.

**Choosing** which of the above solutions you choose is often dependent on the features of your operating system.

**PS** It could also be that I'm not understanding your question correctly. In that case, never mind...